# How to return model rows where id is equal to id on other table with relations in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

For example I have:

```
// Returns all projects
$projects = Projects::all();
```

To return categories, belonging to project, I use relationships and can do something like:

```
foreach($projects as $project) { ...show $project->categories... }
```

I need only specific projects, which are followed by specific user. On my `projects_followers` table I have `user_id` and `project_id`.

To retrieve projects which were followed I have this peace of code:

```
$projects = Project::rightJoin(DB::raw('(select * from projects_followers group by project_id) projects_followers'),'projects_followers.project_id','=','projects.id')->get();
// Note: This code doesn't include specifuc user_id.
```

It does retrieve specific rows, but the problem with this code is that laravel relationhips dont work on them. For example `$project->categories` return empty.

```
// Relationship
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}
```

How do I retrieve my model specific rows and make relationships to work?

Comment: It will be helpful for understanding the problem if you can provide an ER diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your question is:

> How do I get projects liked/followed by Auth/Logged in User ?

Unfortunately you described it in such a way that it looks something else, anyways. Lets try to find the solution and for this I would like to use something like this:

```
$projects = Auth::user()->favorite_projects;
```

So how we can implement this to work,  first of all the `User Model` should contain the method `favoriteProjects` so lets create it:

```
public function favoriteProjects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\Project',
        'projects_followers', // This table already exists as you mentioned
        'user_id',
        'project_id'
    );
}
```

That's it. You will be able to load the projects followed by the current user and other relationship methods will work on every single project as well.

Comment: „Unfortunately you described it in such a way that it looks something else<...>“. Well basically because I didn't know about such a simple solution. Should I edit my question or leave it as it is?

Answer (score 0):

My workaround:

```
  // I don't know how to create empty collection, so impossible conditions here.
  $projects = Project::where('id', 0)->get();

  $follows = DB::table('projects_followers')->where('follower_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

  foreach($follows as $follow) {
    $project = Project::where('id', $follow->project_id)->first();
    $projects = $projects->add($project);
  }
```